# Problem with random numbers for RSA.generate from PyCryptodome

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycryptodome, python-cryptography

I try to use PyCryptodome for producing RSA key with a call to os.urandom to first get som random numbers. I
must do some statistical testing and processing on the random data before i generate the RSA keys. I can use a file object to for loading the random numbers from file. I'm really scratching my head on this one..

```
fx = open("rnd.dat", "rb")
key = RSA.generate(1024, fx.read)
```

The code below works.

```
key = RSA.generate(1024, v1.readstd()) #Works!
```

The code here doesn't .

```
key = RSA.generate(1024, v1.read())    #Not working....
```

I have included the source.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA # PyCryptodome
from Crypto import Random
import os

class trng:
   def __init__(self, rngval): 
      self.rngval = rngval 
   def read(self):
      return self.rngval 
   def readstd(self):
      return Random.get_random_bytes

rngbuff=os.urandom(1024)
#....Here will go some processing
#..
#....end
v1 = trng(rngbuff)

key1 = RSA.generate(1024, v1.readstd()) #Works! 

fx = open("rnd.dat", "rb")  
key2 = RSA.generate(1024, fx.read) #Works! 

key3 = RSA.generate(1024, v1.read())    #Not working....
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `RSA.generate` takes `randfunc` as a function object while in your code you call the function itself resulting in `self.rngval` to be passed to the function as a parameter which itself is the random bytes returned by `os.urandom` which doesn't have a read method so this will fail.
so you need to call function as

```
key3 = RSA.generate(1024, v1.read)
```

As a side note I don't see how you can use this return value from `os.urandom` as the input to `RSA.generate` since `RSA.generate` `randfunc` is supposed to be used as a function that return a random number which is kept calling until it returns a prime random number. unless you make sure that this number (`rngbuff`) is a valid prime number of needed length.

Comment: I didn't understand that RSA.generate repeatably keeps calling until it finds a prime number.

Comment: @MatsStenfeldt It does that since these prime numbers need to be generated randomly. But if you are sure that ```rngbuff``` is a prime number of  ```size >= key bits``` I guess this can work although i didn't try that

Comment: Yes i'm sure of that. I'm reading from a binary file that is produced by a true random number generator and it is checked in accordance to FIPS 140-2 on-line tests. Monobit, Poker and Runs.